# A Number Theory Olympiad problem

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Find the least possible value of $a+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $11$ divides $a+13b$ and $13$ divides $a+11b$.

What I have tried:

Since $13$ divides $a+11b$, $13$ also divides $a-2b$.

Since $11$ divides $a+13b$, 11 also divides $a+2b$

Also GCD$(11,13)=1$. I don't know how to progress from here.

Comment: can $a,b$ are arbitrary integers numbers, also $$a=56,b=101$$? or numbers from $0$ to $9$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @Arthur Nope, I have just heard about it.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner they can be arbitrary integers, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ans: $a = 23,b = 5$

let $a-2b = 13k_1$ 
$a+2b=11k_2$,

$a = \frac{13k_1+11k2}{2} \ b = \frac{11k_2-13k_1}{4}$
 since $b > 0$, $11k_2 > 13k_1 -(i)$

$a+b = \frac{13k_1+33k_2}{4}$

note that $k_2 > 0$ (as $a,b >0$)

also $11k_2 - 13k_1$ is multiple of 4 $-(ii)$

so choosing $k_2 = 1$ $by \ (i) \ k_1 <=  0$, but $k_1 \not = 0 \ by\  (ii)$ also $ if k_1 < 0 $ we do not get any solution

Proceeding similarly we get $k_2 = 3$ and $k_1 = 1$.

PS. please check of some silly mistakes. Thanks